# Assigning a class to a variable in Django views

Tags: class, python-2.7, django-views

I am reading up these block of codes (found within a function in a Django views file) where the class Job is assigned to a variable job, as seen below (refer to the last 6 lines).The codes are not found online.

I have not come across this method of calling an external class before. Is this the usual way of assigning a class to a variable in Django?

Thanks!

```
def ajax_save_job(request,session):
    c = {}
    user_model = session.get_property('user_model')
    userid = user_model.get_property('UserID')
    JobID = request.POST.get('JobID',False)
    collectAddress = request.POST.get('collectAddress',False)
    collectContactNumber = request.POST.get('collectContactNumber',False)
    collectContactName = request.POST.get('collectContactName',False)
    deliverAddress = request.POST.get('deliverAddress',False)
    deliverContactNumber = request.POST.get('deliverContactNumber',False)
    deliverContactName = request.POST.get('deliverContactName',False)
    collectCompanyName = request.POST.get('collectCompanyName',False)
    deliverCompanyName = request.POST.get('deliverCompanyName',False)
    price = request.POST.get('price',False)
    parcelWeight = request.POST.get('parcelWeight',False)
    parcelSize = request.POST.get('parcelSize',False)
    collectDate = request.POST.get('collectDate',False)
    collectTimeFrom = request.POST.get('collectTimeFrom',False)
    collectTimeEnd = request.POST.get('collectTimeEnd',False)
    deliverDate = request.POST.get('deliverDate',False)
    deliverTimeFrom = request.POST.get('deliverTimeFrom',False)
    deliverTimeEnd = request.POST.get('deliverTimeEnd',False)
    rearrangementStatus = request.POST.get('rearrangementStatus',False)
    rearrangementMaxLimit = request.POST.get('rearrangementMaxLimit',False)
    RearrangementExpiry = request.POST.get('RearrangementExpiry',False)
    parcelDescription = request.POST.get('parcelDescription',False)
    collectedon = request.POST.get('collectedon',False)
    deliveredon = request.POST.get('deliveredon',False)
    collectPostal = request.POST.get('collectPostal',False)
    deliverPostal = request.POST.get('deliverPostal',False)
    assignedTo = request.POST.get('assignedTo',False)
    status = request.POST.get('status',False)
    job = False
    output = {}
    try:
        job = Job.init(JobID,index="JobID",multiple=False)
        if (job.properties['status'].lower() == 'processing' or job.properties['status'].lower() == 'bidding') and assignedTo != job.properties['assignedTo'] :
            status ='Assigned'
    except:
        job = False
```

> class Job(Base):
>
> ```
> table = 'tbl_jobs'
> index = 'JobID'
>
> def __init__(self,**kwargs):
>     Base.__init__(self)
>     self.keys = ['JobID']
>     self.required_property_list = ['postByUserID','price']
>     self.unique_properties = []
>     self.db_fields = ['paypalToken','JobID','postByUserID','jobName','parcelDescription','parcelSize','parcelWeight','declaredValue','collectDate','collectTimeFrom','collectTimeEnd','collectContactName','collectContactNumber','collectPostal','collectAddress','collectRegion','collectLatitude','collectLongitude','deliverDate','deliverTimeFrom','deliverTimeEnd','deliverContactName','deliverContactNumber','deliverPostal','deliverAddress','deliverRegion','deliverLatitude','deliverLongitude','biddingTime','biddingTimeEnd','price','postedOn','assignedTo','posted_by','PAID','jobType','status','paymentMethod','collectCompanyName','deliverCompanyName','collectSelfRefName','deliverSelfRefName','collectContactEmail','deliverContactEmail']
>
>     if len(kwargs) == 0:
>         return
>
>     for key in kwargs:     
>         self.properties[key] = kwargs[key] 
>
>     missing_properties = self.required_properies()
>     if len(missing_properties) > 0:
>         raise UserModelPropertyMissingException('Required Property Missing',missing_properties)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me - and this is just a guess - like what's happening here is that you're creating an instance of Job with the given id, and by telling it "multiple=False", you mean that if it already exists, you want that existing one, and not a new one - sort of a get-or-create flag. Then, you maybe use that job's status to update the status of whatever it is you're up do.

Obviously, not having more to go on, this is just a stab in the dark.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I added in the class Job codes as well.